# How to manually stub out a function in C# unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to create my own Mock function. I know Moq exists, but I really want to accomplish this.

I have no idea how I'd create a Mock function to stub out User#Foobar's calls to Product#Price in order to unit test User#Foobar:

```
using System;

public class MyUnitTest
{
    // CODE BEING TESTED
    class Product {
        public string Price() {
            return "I WANT TO STUB THIS OUT, DONT WANT TO SEE THIS STRING";
        }
    }
    class User {
        public string Foobar() {
            Product product = new Product();
            return $"Foobar, Product#price returns: {product.Price()}";
        }    
    }
    //////////////////////
    
    // CODE THAT DOES THE TEST
    public void Mock(string mockedClass, string mockedFunction, string mockedReturn)
    {
        // no idea what to put here something to do with an interface
    }
    
    public void RunTests()
    {
        Mock("Product","Price","MOCKED DATA");
        string expected = new User().Foobar();
        Assert(expected, "Foobar, Product#price returns: MOCKED DATA");
    }
        
    public void Assert(string actual, string expected){
        Console.WriteLine(actual == expected);
    }
    //////////////////////

    // How do I stub out Product to return "MOCKED DATA"?
}
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(){
        new MyUnitTest().RunTests();
    }
}
```

I know how to do it in Ruby, but not in C#.

Here's a NET fiddle of the problem:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Re2jb

What should this Mock function do to intercept User#Foobar's call to Product#Price and return the string "MOCKED DATA"?

```
public void Mock(string mockedClass, string mockedFunction, string mockedReturn)
{
}
```

Comment: I know how to create a class from a string using CSharpCompiler, but the generated class just goes into a obj variable, and so doesn't get called by the code being tested.

Comment: Using interfaces insteaad of concrete implementations would really make it easier. The same would using dependency injection. When Foobar creates the Product instances you have a hard time getting to it. And if you find a solution to all this, I'm not sure it would be caleld mocking. And lo and behold: As I'm writing this comment Matthew Watson comes with an answer that does just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should approach this by using dependency injection. The `User` object shouldn't know the concrete type of the `Product`. Instead, you should encapsulate `Product` behind an `IProduct` interface and pass to the `User` constructor either an `IProduct` or some kind of `IProduct` factory.

For example:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    public string Price();
}

public interface IUser
{
    public string FooBar();
}

public class User: IUser
{
    public User(Func<IProduct> productFactory)
    {
        _productFactory = productFactory;
    }

    public string FooBar()
    {
        var product = _productFactory();
        return $"Foobar, Product#price returns: {product.Price()}";
    }

    readonly Func<IProduct> _productFactory;
}
```

Then you can create your own "mock" product (which we should really call a stub):

```
public class MockProduct : IProduct
{
    public MockProduct(string mockPrice)
    {
        _mockPrice = mockPrice;
    }

    public string Price()
    {
        return _mockPrice;
    }

    readonly string _mockPrice;
}
```

Then in your test you can create the `User` and pass to it a factory method to create a mock `IProduct`:

```
Func<IProduct> mockProductFactory = () => new MockProduct("MOCKED DATA");

User user = new User(mockProductFactory);

// Test user now.
```

Although this is really a form of stubbing (a term you already used) rather than mocking - mocking is generally done with a mocking framework and uses reflection to avoid having to manually implement all the methods in an interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Ruby you can mock from the testing code, the source code you're testing isn't changed at all. With C# projects, do you need to explicitly change your source code? So all objects you want to unit test need a to accept a "Func<Iwhatever>"? Do you set this up as an optional argument so it isn't used when the code is running in production? Does this question make sense?

Comment: @CaptainDucko I don't know Ruby, but in C# you have to use Dependency Injection as above (same for Java)

Comment: Ok. Ruby is a very...creative language which as it's advantages and disadvantes.  Just to spell it out for me (I'm super, super dumb), if you want to unit test your c# project, all classes in your project must accept a Func<Interface?

Comment: No, they don't all need that specific interface. You could instead pass in the object rather than a factory to create the object. For example, for your `User` class you could change the constructor to `public User(IProduct product)` instead, and store the product in a field in the class for use in `User.FooBar()`.

Comment: Have a look at this Microsoft documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection

Comment: If you want to learn even more about this, I can recommend the book "Dependency injection in .net" by "Mark Seemann". This is considered one of the best books about it.