# How to avoid a fatal() in method when testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've got some code that reads some text and tries to execute it as a sql query.

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new(stream))
    {
        var commandText = reader.ReadToEnd();

        SqlCommand cmd = new(commandText, conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            CommandTimeout = timeoutInSeconds
        };

        foreach (string s in parameters)
        {
            string[] fields = s.Split(':');
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[0], fields[1]);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal("Failed to execute query: " + ex.Message);
}
```

We've got a library that has a `Fatal()` and it automatically emails the team and exits after. The problem I'm having is that I want to write a unit test that makes sure this method fails-but I don't want to email the team while testing obviously and I don't want to exit. Is there a way to skip the `fatal()` for testing purposes only?

I was able to get it working by adding an optional command line argument called testMode that is a boolean. Then I added an if() else() around every single `Fatal()` in the program and only allowed the `Fatal()` when it wasn't in test mode. It worked, but it was sloppy, repetitive, and I didn't think the idea of a command line argument for unit testing was a wise approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually stub out a function in C# unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72435054/how-to-manually-stub-out-a-function-in-c-sharp-unit-testing)

Comment: What is the type of the `Log`? Is it an `ILogger`? Also where and how do you instantiate it?